# Baseball Glove Has A Ridge In It

Tags: baseball, equipment, maintenance

I got this new glove, but while I was watching some videos of youtube of gloves, all the gloves don't have a ridge down the middle of the glove.(Around where the part where you close it is.) I was wondering if there was a fix for this or if it was because there was an error in the process of breaking in.

[image]

Comment: You might want to include a picture, and some additional details.  What kind of glove is this?  (Infielder's glove, Outfielder's glove, First basemen's mitt, Catcher's mitt, Pitcher's glove... see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Baseball_glove) for details)

Comment: Here is a picture http://imgur.com/wiq01uT I do not know what type it is though

Answer (score 1):

If this an unused glove you need to properly form it. There are many methods but I always used neetfoot oil to soften the leather and then placed a ball in the pocket and kept it there when not in use. The photo appears to be a bit of a "roll" in the pocket standing up. Just oil it to soften and use it and see if it forms to your liking. I am not saying it is not a good glove but the high quality (and high price) gloves are easier to work with new